# how to save data on database using checkbox in cakephp

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html, cakephp

I am new in cakephp so I want to store value 1 in db when user checked the  check box also stay checked after update please help me to resolve this issue.

One more thing default value to `Userhistory.tillnow` is 0

```
 <?php echo $this->Form->create('Userhistory', array('class' => 'form-inline')); ?>
 <?php echo $this->Form->input('Userhistory.tillnow', array('type' => 'checkbox')); ?>` 
 <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>`
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps

1. Change the Database column to a TINYINT(1) for Boolean columns.
2. Save your request data

   `$this->Userhistory->save($this->request->data);`